# how to count the number of times a word occurs on a webpage with PHP

Tags: php

I need a script that will return a count of how many times a specified word appears on webpage.  Does anyone know how to do this with PHP?  The code will be like this:

```
<?php
$url="watever.com";
the script here
echo(result);
?>
```

I do have this little bit that just gives a count of how many times every word on the webpage appears but I am not quite sure how to modify it for just one word.

```
$str = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
print_r(array_count_values(str_word_count(strip_tags(strtolower($str)), 1)));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [substr_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php):

```
$result = (substr_count(strip_tags($str),"mycoolword"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [**substr_count**](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php).

> substr_count - Count the number of substring occurrences

Answer (score 0):

Look into using preg_match - http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

One of the parameters is $matches, which if passed will put all the matches in that array, so you could get the count by doing a count($matches).

The php page has good examples, here is one:

```
<?php
$subject = "abcdef";
$pattern = '/^def/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

Comment: In this case you will have to use `preg_match_all` since `preg_match` won't find more then one occurrence of the pattern